# Is it possible to use an eclipse plugin project as jar library in a regular java project?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have an eclipse plugin that I would like to access some classes in a regular Java Project. I was wondering if it is possible to generate a jar file from the plugin and then use that jar file in the Java Project. So in summary:

Is it possible to use an eclipse plugin project as jar library in a regular java project?

Thanks,

-- Tiago

Comment: Try it and see.  If it doesn't work, repackage your common classes in a regular Java project.  That common classes JAR should be usable in your plug-in project and your other Java project.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17350647/2226988) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time,an Eclipse plugin is exactly a jar file/few jar files,and on some other conditions it contains a `features` folder and other type files.For a single jar which is added dependency to this project,any public/static members can be accessible.

So just add it to the project's build path and you can access them.